# jQuery function not calling on modal close

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I want to call a function that processes my datatable at the serverside when I close a bootstrap modal.

This is my jquery

```
$('#launch').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    fill_datatable();
    console.log(123);
});
console.log(333);
function fill_datatable(filter_status = ''){
    var dataTable = $('#dataTable2').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "columnDefs": [
        { "searchable": true, "targets": 0 }
      ],
    "serverSide" : true,
    "createdRow": function(row, data, index) {
        switch (data[8]) {
            default:
                $(row).css('background-color', 'white');
        }
    },
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
        url:"ajax/fetch.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{ filter_status:filter_status }
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        { "width": "40%", "targets": 3,
          "className": "text-justify", "targets": 3,
          "searchable": true, "targets": 3,
        }
      ]
   });
  }
```

When the modal closes I can see `123` in my console but it doesnt call the `fill_datatable()` function, which is placed directly outside of the `on()` method.

Note that the `fill_datatable()` function works because it processes the table on page load, but I want it to refresh after an action is done in the modal so I see the latest changes.

Comment: If you put a console.log right at the top of fill_datatable does it log? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: @BrettGregson The console message right at the top of the function doesnt show when i close the modal, although it shows on page load. And its not showing any console errors either.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the fill_datatable function definition (doesn't have to be the whole function, just exactly where it is in relation to your modal hide functionality)

Comment: Done. The `console.log(333)` doesnt show on modal close.

Comment: Put the console.log inside your function: `function fill_datatable(filter_status = ''){ console.log(333)...`

Comment: Instead of making function you can add the whole code in on('hidden.bs.modal', functio

Comment: 333 is showing in the console when i placed it inside the function

Comment: @SagarKodte I tried it and got the same results.

Comment: It sounds like you function is being called but not doing what you expect. If the log is showing, then the problem is within the fill_datatable function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroy the dataTable method before calling the function, using `$('#dataTable2').DataTable().destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Try define function fill_datatable() before $('#launch').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {}.